# How to prove the efficiency of Carnot engine is bigger than Otto engine

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

I know the Carnot engine has maximum efficiency among all engines from  Clausius statement, but how to prove the relationship of these two engines in equation? Thanks.
More specifically, the efficiency of Carnot engine is $$1-T_L/T_H$$ and Otto engine is $$1-(V_2/V_1)^{r-1}$$However, I have no idea how to compare these two different types of equations.

Comment: Have you tried to do the analysis. You need to show some effort otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: Do you mean calculate the efficiencies of the two engines so you can compare them? If so the Carnot efficiency is $(T_{hot} - T_{cold})/T_{hot}$ so that's easy. I don't know the efficiency of an Otto engine but I'm sure it could easily be googled.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain my question well. I just edited my question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I have no idea how to compare these two different types of
> equations.

Rather than attempt to compare those equations, it may be more instructive to express the first equation in terms of the temperatures involved in the Otto cycle to determine the Otto cycle efficiency in terms of temperatures. If you do, you will find that the efficiency of the Carnot engine cycle is greater than the efficiency of the Otto engine cycle because, for the Carnot cycle, the heat transfers occur between two fixed temperatures whereas for the Otto cycle the heat transfers occur over a range of temperatures.

To show this, consider the T-S diagrams below for an idealized (reversible) Otto cycle and the Carnot heat engine cycle, where both operate between the same temperature extremes.

Note that for the Carnot cycle all the heat added and rejected occur at a single maximum and minimum temperature of the cycle. For the Otto cycle the heat added and rejected occurs over a range of temperatures.

The efficiency of the Carnot cycle is

$$\eta_{Carnot}=1-\frac{T_L}{T_H}=1-\frac{T_1}{T_2}$$

For the Otto cycle the efficiency can be approximated by the equation

$$\eta_{Otto}=1-\frac{T_{Lm}}{T_{Hm}}$$

where $T_{Lm}$ and $T_{Hm}$ are the mean (average) values of the temperatures at which heat is rejected and added, respectively, in the Otto cycle.

Note that

$$T_{Lm}\gt T_1$$

Let's call the difference $+\Delta T_1$.

And

$$T_{Hm}\lt T_2$$

Let's call the difference

$$-\Delta T_2$$

Then the efficiency of the Otto cycle can be expressed in terms of the equation

$$\eta_{Otto}=1-\frac{(T_{1}+\Delta T_1)}{(T_{2}-\Delta T_2)}$$

It can be shown that any combination of values of $\Delta T_1$ and $\Delta T_2$ will result in $\eta_{Carnot}\gt\eta_{Otto}$. More generally, this means the Carnot efficiency will be greater than any heat engine cycle, not just the Otto cycle, that operate between the same maximum and minimum temperatures.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this really help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common sort of homework problem, so I'll just give an outline of how it can be addressed and leave the details to you.

[Via Wikipedia, we have an (idealized) $PV$ diagram for the Otto cycle:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_cycle)

[image]

It is also possible to show (see the analysis at the above link) that the efficiency of this cycle is $\eta_\text{Otto} = 1 - T_1/T_2$, where $T_1$ and $T_2$ are the temperatures at the given points in the cycle.

To compare this to the Carnot efficiency, you need to see how this efficiency compares to $\eta_\text{Carnot} = 1 - T_L/T_H$, where $T_L$ is the lowest temperature attained in the Otto cycle and $T_H$ is the highest.  If all you want to do is to prove that $\eta_\text{Otto} \leq \eta_\text{Carnot}$, the easiest way to proceed is to figure out whether $T_1 = T_L$ or $T_1 > T_L$, and whether $T_2 = T_H$ or whether $T_2 < T_H$.  With the answers to those questions, you should be able to prove that $\eta_\text{Otto} \leq \eta_\text{Carnot}$ fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep working on it.